# "Театр военных действий" — почему театр?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

О плане какого-то большого сражения говорят, что это "театр военных действий". Но почему — театр, какое отношение имеет театр, где все понарошку, к настоящей войне, где убивают взаправду?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ в особенностях словообразования в русском языке от заимствованных слов.

Теа́тр (греч. θέατρον) основное значение — место для зрелищ, затем — зрелище, от θεάομαι — смотрю, вижу) — зрелищный вид искусства, отсюда-
•   детский театр(зрелище для детей)
•   кукольный театр(зрелище с использованием кукол)
•   театр одного актёра(зрелище, создаваемое 1 актёром)

Театр военных действий - словообразование пошло от первой части значения:не от "зрелище", а от "место"-театр, ограниченное пространство, но если там было ограниченное пространство для зрелищ, то здесь ограниченное пространство для военных действий. Точка соприкосновения-место, ограниченное пространство.